# CSS rounded corners done quickly: is this an awful technique?

Tags: css, rounded-corners

Here's a quick and dirty round corners technique I've been playing around with.

```
<!-- assuming the div isn't statically positioned -->
<div>
    <img src="box_TL.png" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"/>
    <img src="box_TR.png" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;"/>

    <!-- other content -->

    <img src="box_BL.png" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;"/>
    <img src="box_BR.png" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;"/>
</div>
```

Yeah it's ugly, but it's fast, the corners are fluid, it avoids nested divs and requires no javascript. The corner images and content order makes no difference, but I thought it might be more intuitive to order corners and content this way.

**Question:** How terrible is this technique? Is it passable or should I abandon it completely?

Comment: In such cases, isn't it important to also ask in how many browser types/versions this has to work?

Comment: good point, I don't know all the cross-browser quirks, however IE6 is out since I remember reading it has bad/zero position:absolute support. Hopefully some css gurus will point out the relevant browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's terrible.  Your markup should be content, and your layout should be in the style.  Not intermingled.  You should go with:

```
<div class="whatitis">
   bla blah ... content here
</div>
```

and the style:

```
.whatitis {
    background: whatever;
    border: whatever;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Yes, sure, some browsers won't get rounded corners.  But if you hack up a solution that will give properly rounded cornsers even in browsers that does not support that, you will have a complex solution, and odds are that your site will not work att all in some other browsers.  So you should ask yourself: What is more important, that the site works at all in some browser X or that you get rounded corners in some other browser Y?

Addition:  Using the jQuery plugin mentioned in another answer (or some other pre-packaged solution) might be accepptable.  As long as it does *not* require any extra `<div>`, `<img>` or other tags.

Comment: By now there is also the http://css3pie.com/ solution, that makes the above style work even with MSIE 6 - 8.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use [jQuery Corner Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/). It's *very* fast and works in all modern browsers, **and also** in IE6.

Comment: not the perfect solution, but will work for 90% of my projects

Comment: +1 - for things like this keep your HTML semantic and lose all the extra divs, imgs, etc if they're just there for decoration and add them using progressive enhancement javascript. Using a library will avoid cross-browser problems and link to one of the hosted copies and visitors will most likely have it in their cache already.

Comment: Did you just call IE6 a modern browser? ;)

Comment: jQuery for adding rounded corners is a bit too much in my opinion. yes it's easy, but you require 60kb+ of Javascript and it will not work in browsers with JavaScript disabled. Plus you are very limited if you want to use anything else than plain flat colors (no shadows, no gradients etc). And my guess is that the output from it is pretty messy code, even though normal people will never see it. Wont give it a downvote, since it's a plausible solution, but I'd never use it myself. Too messy and too little control.

Comment: @Arve: It's actually 8.1KB, and not 60KB. Minimized version 4.9KB. You can minify this using something like this http://www.galasoft-lb.ch/mydotnet/GalaSoftLb.Utilities/jsmin.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's a terrible solution, sorry :-)

It's true that you don't need any JavaScript or nested `div` elements. The JavaScript is easily avoidable, no matter what. But is four irrelevant `img` elements better than a few nested `div` elements? The `img` element is supposed to contain image content, using it for layout purposes is basically the same as using tables for layout. Yes, it works, but it's wrong, and it ruins all semantic value.

If I were you, I'd do it this way (excuse the silly class-names, they are just there to illustrate):

#### The markup

```
<div class="boxWithRoundedCorners">
    <div class="roundedCornersTop">
        <div class="roundedCornersTopRight"></div>
    </div>

    <p>Your content goes here, totally unaffected by the corners at all. Apply all necessary margin and other styling to make it look good.</p>

    <div class="roundedCornersBottom">
        <div class="roundedCornersBottomRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The CSS

```
.boxWithRoundedCorners { background: red; }
.roundedCornersTop { 
    background: url(topLeftCornerPlusTheTopOfTheBox.gif); /* Should be pretty long. Assuming your corners are 20*20px, this could for instance be 1000*20px, depending on how large the box would ever be in the real world */
    height: 20px;
}

.roundedCornersTopRight {
    background: url(topRightImage.gif);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.roundedCornersBottom { background: url(topBottomCornerPlusTheBottomOfTheBox.gif); /* same "rule" as above */
    height: 20px;
}

.roundedCornersBottomRight {
    background: url(bottomRightImage.gif);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

Got it? Hang on, I'll put up an example somewhere :-)

**Edit:** Just threw up an [an example](http://dev.systadmedia.no/demo/html_css/fluidRoundedCorners/)!

Anyhow, this method will ensure a complete flexibility regarding height and width of the box, and the layout within the box always works the way it should, unaffected by the corners.
Yes, it gives you some nested divs with no purpose other than the layout - but then again, that's what DIVs are used for. IMGs should always be content-related imagery.

You could do it with all the corners being 15*15px  and setting the background-color of the container. However, when stretching these images like this, you get the opportunity to add shadows, gradients or other effects. This is what I'm used to do, so I did this this way with the stretched images.

This method is well tested out, and should as far as I know/remember work fine at least all the way back to IE 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old topic, but since it's re-appeared on the front page, I'll add a comment.

In the last few months, a new solution has appeared for rounded corners, which solves the issue for all relevant versions of IE (6,7,8).

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is a 'hack' for IE which allows you to set up rounded corners in your CSS and not worry about it anywhere else. At a stroke, you can throw away all those extra divs in your markup and those jquery plugins, and just specify it in your stylesheet the way it should be.

All other browsers support rounded corners in CSS, and have done so for long enough that you don't need to worry about older versions.

CSS3Pie also helps with CSS gradients and box shadows in IE too, so it's a very big win for cross-browser developers.

Answer (score 0):

you'll come into issues with IE6 using PNGs so you will either need to add the correct CSS filter background to divs instead of images or use javascript to help turn the png images into transparent gifs with the png background added.

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Comment: You may say "to hell", but most people on IE6 don't have a choice because their IT is so heavily linked in with microsoft technologies from way back when. It is proven that the shift from IE7 to IE8 hasn't made a dent on IE6's usage.

Comment: I only concern myself in making it as userfriendly in IE6 as in real browsers. But let their eyes bleed a little..

Comment: I make it work in Opera/FF, check that IE8 works (on `edge`, it usually does). Minor tweaks for IE7; IE6 renders as crap anyway, so I conditionally degrade for it. Most of the time, providing full&perfect display for IE6 is too much hassle for insignificant outcome. No rounded corners, no PNG transparency? Tough.

Answer (score 0):

If the box is fixed width, then there's an interesting trick you can do which works in IE8 and the rest (but not IE7-):

```
div.rounded {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

div.rounded:before,
div.rounded:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 600px;
  height: 10px;
}

div.rounded:before { background: url(images/rounded_top.png); }
div.rounded:after { background: url(images/rounded_bottom.png); }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with anything that has a fluid width, and it's not copatible with older IE browsers, but I still like it :)